# LLN interpretation of high-dimensional unit ball mass distribution

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26095/141089) on Math Overflow points out that

> For instance, the fact that most of the mass of a unit ball in high
>   dimensions lurks near the boundary of the ball can be interpreted as a
>   manifestation of the law of large numbers, using the interpretation of
>   a high-dimensional vector space as the state space for a large number
>   of trials of a random variable.

I can hardly make any sense of it.

Anyway, here is my attempt: instead of addressing an $N$-dimensional unit ball, let's consider an $N$-dimensional unit cube first. Each point on that cube can be expressed with a coordinate consisting of $N$ numbers, i.e. $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_N)$, with $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{Uniform}[-1, 1]$. This independence is a result of the orthogonality of axes.

It is trivial to show that $E(X_i^2) = \frac{1}{3}$. Applying the Law of Large Numbers, the (euclidean) distance from a point $P$ to $\mathbb{O}$ is then

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
d(P, \mathbb{O}) &\stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2 + ... + X_N^2} \\
E\left(d(P, \mathbb{O})^2\right) &= E\left(X_1^2 + X_2^2 + ... + X_N^2\right) \\
&\rightarrow \frac{N}{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

Recall that we are interested in the unit ball, so we have to somehow calculate the distribution of $d(P, \mathbb{O})^2 | d(P, \mathbb{O})^2 \le 1$, but I'm lost here.

My question is, how do you interpret the mass distribution of an $N$-dimensional unit ball with LLN?

Comment: +1 for raising the question. But you cannot interchange the expectation with a nonlinear operator. $E\left(d(P, \mathbb{O})\right) < \sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}$.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for pointing that out! I've edited the post to use $d^2$ instead.

Comment: It seems to me LLN is not the right metaphor/whatever. The point is that if you have a large number of iid random variables uniformly distributed in ${-1,1}$, the probability that *at least one* of the random variables is within $\varepsilon$ of either -1 or 1 increases towards 1 as N goes to infinity.

Comment: @pseudocydonia I see your point, but how is this related to a high-dimensional unit ball?

Comment: It applies most directly to the unit n-cube.

Comment: At any rate, Terry commented again on the mathoverflow post you're interested in, and said that the LLN is *not* the right thing to think about here and that he misspoke.